# iOS Safari development ".local" domain issue

Tags: ios, proxy, safari, dns, subdomain

1) I have a ASP.NET app running on my PC (under "xyz.local" domain)
2) I have a third party DNS configured on my PC (created a zone for "xyz.local")
3) I have a Fiddler proxy running at port 8888
4) I have a Windows and iOS tablets with DNS configured with my desktop PC's IP address and proxy configured with my desktop PC's IP address and Fiddler proxy port (8888)

On Windows tablet, I can access my web app with both IE and Chrome via "xyz.local".
On iOS tablet, I can access my web app with Chrome, but not with Safari. Requests from Safari don't even reach Fiddler. I was suggested that Safari requires that I add WWW at the start, so I tried with "www.xyz.local" (I added that as an alias(CNAME) to dns records) and nothing. But, then I tried setting all up for "www.xyz.com" and it worked.

Anybody knows why? I really need to go with ".local" and not ".com" TLD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 6762 reserves the top-level label `.local` for multicast DNS. Do not use `.local` for ordinary DNS. Use a real, registered domain name instead. If you absolutely positively cannot use a real domain, at least pick one of the reserved names that are guaranteed never to be used as TLDs (`.invalid`, `.localhost`, `.test` and `.example`).

The reason it accidentally works for you on Windows is that Windows by default does not use mDNS. OSX, iOS and Android does.

Comment: Apple may be following the RFC, but all other platforms (including Linux and Android by default - contrary to this answer - as mDNS is configurable) end up supporting the reality of .local private hostnames. We use IP addresses on iOS when we want to proxy in order to work-around this problem - quite inconvenient